# PrimeFaces.settings.locale coming undefined while using primefaces 6.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

PrimeFaces.settings.locale coming undefined while using prime faces 6.1.
Also PrimeFaces.settings coming as blank object. Please help 
Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please check all your tags. One is very wrong. And does it work with 6.0?

Comment: It is working for 5.3 version. Same Issue I am facing in 6.0 also.